# Does Cloud Spanner allow me to scale storage separately from compute?

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

I see a lot of claims that Spanner decouples compute from storage. And sure the diagrams look like it does. However, when scaling Spanner the only dial I can turn is the number of nodes in the cluster. Each node is provisioned with some compute and 2TB of storage.

What's nice is that even if I over-provision nodes past my storage needs, I still only pay for the storage I'm using. So in that sense, the costs for compute and storage are also decoupled.

But what if my storage scales faster than compute? If I have 10TB of data I need 5 (really 6) nodes. But what if there just aren't enough queries to use even 10% of the available compute on those nodes? Unlike storage, I don't pay for used compute hours. I pay for the node as long as it's provisioned and I can't deprovision it because I need the storage space.

This means Spanner does not actually separate compute from storage in a strict sense. Since my compute costs scale with storage (as well as with queries per second), this claim seems almost blatantly false.

It's possible that Spanner is simply not intended for a use case where compute scales slower than storage, but I feel like I must be misunderstanding something. Please help me see the error of my ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `I pay for the node as long as it's provisioned and I can't deprovision it because I need the storage space.`

  Unfortunately that is true.

  Maintaining the data itself incurs not only CPU but also memory cost. So there is a limit to how much data a node can efficiently handle. The claim of separation of compute/storage still holds until the limit is reached.
- `It's possible that Spanner is simply not intended for a use case where compute scales slower than storage.`

  I am afraid there is no workaround this limit ATM. But I do agree that this is a valid use case and Cloud Spanner probably should have a solution to handle it.

  Although it does not directly address your concern - you can open a feature request to provide a data point and help the team better prioritize.